# how to update price and quantity in bulk using rest api

Tags: magento2

Sir, 
    For single product price and quantity update is working,i want to update bulk for price and quantity using rest api.
Can u provide the procedure for bulk update.

Comment: Which code you have to use single product price and quantity update. Please paste the code here.

Comment: "http://localhost/magento2.0/rest/V1/products/"+sku ;   this url i had used for single price update. "http://localhost/magento2.0/rest/V1/products/"+sku+"/stockItems/1";     this url  for single quantity update

Comment: I want to do bulk update of price and quantity using magento rest api only.Can u provide us the procedure for bulk update using rest api .